# A function that takes x and returns the largest power of 2 less than or equal to the number

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that takes a positive number and returns it with the largest power of 2 less than or equal to that number.

For example,

```
pow2(12)->8
```

I am having trouble with my code:

```
 import math
import random

def pow2(n):
    return 2**int(math.log(n,2))

pow2(12)
```

Is my code doing what its suppose to do? Why isn't it returning a number?

Comment: it _is_ returning a number. You don't see it because you aren't printing it. Try `print(pow2(12))`

Comment: Also I believe the `import random` is superfluous to your problem.

Comment: Also it gives a wrong answer for example for `n=0.6` (because casting to `int` rounds towards zero).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with not assigning the return value to a variable

```
import math
import random

def pow2(n):
    return 2**int(math.log(n,2))

x = pow2(12) # here
print(x)
```

Alternatively you could

```
print(pow2(12))
```